# Input array shows exception in thread "main" java.lang.negativearraysizeexception

Tags: java, java-8

It works fine on VS Code, but when I run it on the compiler required for our training exam ,it shows the above error. What could be the reason?

What does it mean? I'm new to programming languages. So please ignore my mistake.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class sum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Write solution here

        int n = 0, sum = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        n = sc.nextInt();

        int arr[] = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();

            if (arr[0] == 0) {

                System.out.println("No elements to sum");

                break;

            }

            else if (arr[0] < 0) {

                System.out.println("Invalid number of elements");

                break;

            }

            else {

                sum = sum + arr[i];

            }

        }

        System.out.println(sum);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It means that [`n` is negative](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NegativeArraySizeException.html).

Comment: @AndyTurner how? How can we solve this issue sir?

Comment: "how?" because it's reading a negative number from the scanner. "How can we solve this issue" you need to understand what is being passed into your program. I don't know.

Comment: The condition was to show "invalid number of elements" when a negative number is entered.

Comment: OK, so in between the `n = sc.nextInt();` and `int arr[] = new int[n];` lines, you need to do something more.

Comment: @AndyTurner while(n>0) ?

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: It shows Errors.

Comment: @Matt Have you considered using a statement to check if n is a valid number?

Comment: The problem is, when i run the program and provide the inputs(even a negative no.), it doesn't show any error, but when the compiler checks with its own test cases, it shows the above error. I'm confused.

Comment: In between when you read `n` and when you create the array, you do not do anything to validate that `n` is positive. Also, during the loop, you keep checking `arr[0]` to see if it is zero or negative. But these are the constraints you should be putting on `n`, not on `arr[0]`.

Comment: I put arr[0] because condition said that if the first input was a 0 or a negative then we have to show the respective output...

Answer (score 0):

The exception `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException` means that you attempted to create an array with a negative size. An array with a negative size does not make sense, so it throws this exception.

The exception must be thrown on the line `int arr[] = new int[n];` since this is the only place where you created an array, and the cause of the exception is that `n` is negative. Since you define `n` as `n = sc.nextInt();`, `n` is negative when a negative number is passed into stdin (the command line).

It looks from your code that `n` is supposed to be the number of elements to be summed; however, when you check to see if there is a negative number of elements, you write `if (arr[0] < 0)`. This is checking if the first element of the array is less than zero which is not the same as `n`: `n` is the length of the array. To prevent a `NegativeArraySizeException` you need to check if `n` is negative before you attempt to create an array of size `n`.

Also I don't know why you put

```
if (arr[0] == 0) {

       System.out.println("No elements to sum");

       break;

 }

 else if (arr[0] < 0) {

       System.out.println("Invalid number of elements");

       break;

 }
```

inside the loop: there is no point in checking for each iteration since the value of `arr[0]` (and `n`) is not going to change.